# Return the last row in mysql query from left join

Tags: php, mysql, join

I am trying to get the last row of table2 that I left join with table1.

**Table1 column:**

1. id
2. name
3. created date

**Table2 column:**

1. id
2. last_login
3. ip_address

Login data stored into table2 everytime user logged in. So I am trying to display all users from table1 which is displaying the `last_login` record from table2.

Here is my current query :

```
SELECT table1.*, table2.last_login
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table2.id= table1.id
ORDER BY table2.last_login desc;
```

With the query above I am able to get all the data from both table, where if user A logged 5 times, the query will return 5 rows, but I wanted to only showing the user details and their `last_login` data. If I add `GROUP BY table1.id` it return 1 row record for every user but the `last_login` data is not showing the latest record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want the last login, perhaps a correlated subquery would do:

```
SELECT t1.*,
       (SELECT MAX(t2.last_login)
        FROM table2 t2
        WHERE t2.id = t1.id
       ) as last_login
FROM table1 t1
ORDER BY last_login desc;
```

For performance, you want an index on `table2(id, last_login)`.

Comment: (Which is presumably the PRIMARY KEY)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `MAX` function in SQL

For reference: https://www.techonthenet.com/sql/max.php